# Mock a SOAP Web Service using Mockito and measure the performance of it using JMeter

Tags: web-services, soap, jmeter, automated-tests, mockito

Each of the team that we support should be able to use JMeter for their own performance testing. We have to give a demonstration of how to use JMeter from the developers perspective. How you would use Jmeter.
How to use Mockito? When we do LnP testing the services that we are testing have Db2 mainframe access to them. When we do that the mainframe seems to be unpredictable in such a way that, when we run the same test two times in a row, we get two different answers It's because of some kind of mainframes performance problem. We don't want to measure that. We want to measure the service itself. Instead of calling the DB, What we have to do is 'We have to Mock that, mock the method. 
Take one of the Consumer WebService, Create a simple JMeter test with a mock DB and we should be able to demonstrate that.
If we don't have a server, we have to mock that (the service). Take a copy of the software, install it and measure the performance of it.
Maybe do something that changes the performance of it. Whatever it is, when you run it again, it should change the performance of it.

Where to start? I have a project with different modules in it and I can see some Web Service Provider module. Do I need to use JMeter plugin in eclipse for this?
or use JMeter? Please suggest.

Comment: Mockito simulates function calls. Not sure how that can help with JMeter which works on protocol level. Can you give a concrete example?

Comment: @KirilS. Even I don't have any clue. My manager asked me to prepare a demo for the product teams.

Comment: I think what he wants is something like this: http://www.mock-server.com/